# Разделение строки по ключевым словам. Python

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Имеется строка типа:

```
print("i like apples")
```

Или:

```
var x = 5 + 10
```

Так вот. Имеется список токенов. Вот он:

```
tokenlist = ['print', 'var', '"', '(', ')']
```

Нужно эти строчки разбить и получить из них список конечный токенов.

Для 1-го варианта:

```
tokens = ['print', '(', '"', 'i like apples', '"', ')']
```

Для 2-го варианта:

```
tokens = ['var', 'x', '=', '5', '+', '10']
```

Это не учебная задача! Я недавно изучаю программирование и просто хочу узнать как применить регулярку в своем проекте.
Спасибо тому, кто поможет!

Comment: Список токенов не годится: а) в нем нет некоторых токенов для 2-го варианта, б) с помощью такого вида токенов невозможно выбрать произвольный текст и числа из выражений, нужно как минимум их сделать в виде regex

Comment: будете плодить одинаковые вопросы, будем закрывать их все. Если это не учебное задание, вам нужно показать свои попытки решения.

Answer (score 1):

Если попытаться решить эту задачку на основе исходного tokenlist, то получится что-то вроде:

```
import re

s1 = 'print("i like apples")'
s2 = 'var x = 5 + 10'

tokenlist = ['print', 'var', '"', '(', ')']
out = re.findall('|'.join(re.escape(t) for t in tokenlist), s1)
print(out)
out = re.findall('|'.join(re.escape(t) for t in tokenlist), s2)
print(out)
```

```
['print', '(', '"', '"', ')']
['var']
```

Можно tokenlist немного усовершенствовать:

```
import re

s1 = 'print("i like apples")'
s2 = 'var x = 5 + 10'
tokenlist = ['print', 'var', '\(', '"', '(?<=")[^"]+(?=")', '[a-zA-Z]\w*', '"', '\)', '\d+', '\+', '-', '=']

out = re.findall('|'.join(tokenlist), s1)
print(out)
out = re.findall('|'.join(tokenlist), s2)
print(out)
```

```
['print', '(', '"', 'i like apples', '"', ')']
['var', 'x', '=', '5', '+', '10']
```